# Spark / Cassandra / Datastax connector : How to debug JavaRDD content?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, rdd

I've set up on my laptop a small 3 nodes spark cluster with the DSE 4.6 and ccm tools. I've created a basic keyspace (ks) and a table (chaine) where I've stored strings. I've written a basic java app which uses the Datastax spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10.

When I try to store in JavaRDD the content of this table with that piece of code :

```
   JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("ks", "chaine")
             .map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
                 @Override
                 public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
                     return cassandraRow.toString();
                 }
             });
    System.out.println("Data as CassandraRows: \n" + StringUtils.join(cassandraRowsRDD.collect().toArray(), "\n"));
```

When I execute this app, I do not see any output on the console with the whole content of my table. If I add a println in the overriden call function, I could catch some element which are located on the master node but do not see the data on other nodes of the cluster.

So how could I debug the content of cassandraRowsRDD by printing the string content on the console screen please. Thanks for your help.

Nicolas

Comment: `collect` should be the way to go as you are doing here.

Answer (score 2):

`JavaRDD<String>.collect();` comes handy in debugging.

**Tip:** In intelliJ,  `alt+F8` opens a "expression evaluation" window, which gives the value of your expression immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by using the `toArray()` method of the RDD.  In my project, I was using the `JavaPairRDD`, and using `toArray()` produced a `Tuple2<T,T>` object (which I could iterate through).

In your case, with a `JavaRDD<String>`, `toArray()` should produce a `List<String>` which you should be also able to iterate.

```
for (String row : cassandraRowsRDD.toArray()) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Comment: Be careful, `toArray()` is **deprecated**, use `collect()` instead as @maasg suggested. Sources: [JavaRDDLike documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#toArray())